# Debugging type mismatch error in function

Tags: vbscript

Why am I getting a type mismatch error on line 4 when I execute the below code?

```
Function delete()
    delete= True
End function
delete() = False
if delete() = False then
    MsgBox "Yes"
else
    MsgBox "No"
end if
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign a value to a function this way `delete() = False`

You need to remove this line `delete() = False`. I don't see any use with line 4.

Comment: If i put delete = False then i am getting Illegal assignment error and why it is not giving type mismatch with if statement?

Comment: @user3313770: You need to remove line 4

Comment: @user3313770 You can't assign a value to a function. At all. Functions are not properties.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Though you can assign a value to the function *name*, of course, from within the function. That is, the function's return value.

Comment: @Bond Yes. That's how functions return values in VBScript. And it only works for each function name inside its own body.